# How to get reference of a child tag that was added via dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a div that use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to set some text that come from the server. Something like this:

```
<Wrapper>
  <div
    ref={previewRef}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: preview }}
  />
</Wrapper>
```

The `preview` content it's something like `<p> Some context </p>`. I need to access `offsetHeight` and `scrollHeight` of that rendered `p` tag instead of the `div`.

Comment: Would using the div's ref work? `previewRef.current.querySelector('p')`? Please note that it's not controlled by react

Comment: @evolutionxbox `TypeError: previewRef.current.querySelect is not a function`

Comment: Apologies. `querySelect` -> `querySelector`. Be aware that `current` may be undefined.

Answer (score 0):

According to @evolutionxbox answer. The solution is:

`previewRef.current.querySelector('p')`

Important to validate that `previewRef.current` is not undefined.